# Notification center method method called multiple time ios in Tab bar (View controller)? How to remove observer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, notifications

I am posting notification form one view controller which is in navigation stack in tab bar application. I am removing observer in dealloc as.

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"ArtworkAddedReloadAllArtworks" object:nil];  in dealloc correctly.
```

I am logout as

```
[[self tabBarController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

but issue is when i login back same notification added twice as in Notification center

```
ArtworkAddedReloadAllArtworks, 0x12ff698, 0x7a490e00, 1400
ArtworkAddedReloadAllArtworks, 0x12ff698, 0x7a431800, 1400
```

In Notification center as 2 instance of view controller is created and notification added twice two different objects, How do i unregister notification ? i cant remove from viewDidDisappear as i posting notification from other controller.dealloc is calling after login.

How to make nil view controller(created first before login),and his observer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show the code where you are adding the observer. That will help.

Comment: I think dealloc is not getting called. Debug it to check

Comment: [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(artworkAddedNotificationReceived:) name:@"ArtworkAddedReloadAllArtworks" object:nil];     dealloc calling after i login back

Comment: Where are you adding the observer?

Comment: In same class in viewDidLoad method. and posting notification from another class. it works fine until i logout . after login back 2 view controller with same notification in center appear as above. ...please help me

Comment: @AvijitNagare how do you show your view controller? Maybe you are presenting it twice so `viewDidLoad` gets called twice hence showing you two instances? Also, Add the code by editing your main code

Comment: Try moving the code where you add observer to viewDidAppear and move the code where you remove observer to viewDidDisappear.

Comment: @Greg if i do that notification will not called, from other controller as observer remove in viewDidAppear of added ViewController.

Comment: @NSNoob when you log [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]      ArtworkAddedReloadAllArtworks, 0x12ff698, 0x7a490e00, 1400
ArtworkAddedReloadAllArtworks, 0x12ff698, 0x7a431800, 1400   view controller objects 0x7a490e00 ,0x7a431800

Comment: @NSNoob,@Greg Class B posting notification and Class A is observer  so adding/removing observers to viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear for Class A or Class B ?

Comment: You will remove and add observers obviously for the class which is observing. In your case: Class A. B will simply send a notification which can be received by all classes which are observing that.

Comment: @NSNoob  Now i am in Class A  viewWillAppear called observer added, now i push to Class B then Class A 's viewWillDisappear called and observer removed then how notification will observe by Class A as it removed in viewWillDisappear?

Comment: worked now...thanks all,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If posting class and observing class different then, i can't remove observer in Observing class.

Ex. In Class A viewWillAppear called observer added, now i push to Class B then Class A 's viewWillDisappear called and observer removed now notification won't  observe by Class A as it's removed in viewWillDisappear while push operation.

I think this is not proper solution but i end up by saving observer class reference and used that to remove reference.

Class A (Observing Class) in viewDidLoad method

```
  [[ASNGlobalClass shareManager] setNotificationSelf:self];//Save reference of self
```

Class B(Any Class)

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:[[ASNGlobalClass shareManager] notificationSelf]
                                                    name:@"LookbookChangeNotification"
                                                  object:nil];
```

Comment: Do you really need to observe some changes in ViewController A while it isn't visible? If so, just use solution #2 from my answer

Answer (score 0):

Please check `reuseIdentifier` in Interface Builder. If you set it, `UIViewController` can call `viewDidLoad` multiple times and only once - `dealloc`.
Please check it.

Solution:

Move adding/removing observers to `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear`

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(someSelector:) name:@"ArtworkAddedReloadAllArtworks" object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"ArtworkAddedReloadAllArtworks" object:nil];
}
```

Another solution (I don't like it , but it can help):

Remove observer in `viewDidLoad`, before you add observer

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Remove previously added observer to avoid of duplicate
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"ArtworkAddedReloadAllArtworks" object:nil];
    // Add new observer
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(someSelector:) name:@"ArtworkAddedReloadAllArtworks" object:nil];
}
```

Comment: Class B posting notification and Class A is observer  so adding/removing observers to viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear for Class A or Class B ?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name : UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
```

In this case any observer listening for 'UIKeyboardWillShowNotification' will be removed from within the view controller you are in.

Comment: Call this wherever you want to remove the observer, choosing the appropriate name.