# Common UINavigationController with custom view across application

Tags: ios, swift3, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I am working on a stock market application in which i have to show some indices value which are updated using a socket connection during market hours in the navigation bar.

This feature is common across all screens in the application.

I have subclassed UINavigationController and designed a view in .xib file to show the indices values in `viewDidLoad` and added it as a subview.

[image]

(I am using swift 3.1)

```
    let width = self.view.frame.width - 100.0
    let frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 25, width: width, height: 44)
    viewNavigation = NavigationView(frame: frame)
    self.view.addSubview(viewNavigation!)
```

Is there any other better way to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't seems bad to me.

Having your `window.rootViewController` set as a `UINavigationController` is a good practice I have actually. It can still contain other sub `UINavigationController`

However was is your NavigationView about ? If you're adding a subview directly inside the `navigationController` view property, that's not the expected behaviour and you may have some undefined behaviour happening.

> Following your edited answer and comments:

Yes, I think you should use `UINavigationBar` custom `titleView`.
You can easily set it in different viewController or once :

`self.navBar.topItem?.titleView = NavigationView(frame: frame)`

Comment: should i add it to navigation bar instead of navigation controller?

Comment: Where exactly would you like to display the information ? around the NavigationController navigationBar title ?

Answer (score 0):

I Think you can create UIViewController subclass and add method to show and hide or change values. Please see the example .

BaseViewControler is a sub class on UIViewController

On your BaseViewController write a method as follows

```
func addNavigationTitileView() {
    // add your code to show your value 
  }
```

Now call the in your viewWillAppear

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       super.viewWillAppear(animated)
       addNavigationTitileView()
  }
```

Now you need to create your View controllers subclassing BaseViewController. it automatically add the navigation bar with changes.

For your example better to change navigationTitleView

Lets say you want to display dynamic value on the navigation bar. Using above method it will be easy to update every time when you go to the view controllers.

Now Think you don't want to add that for some view controller you are two options.

1. Create View Controller without subclassing BaseViewController.
2. Create same method on your controller (override ) and method should be blank.

If you want to change text realtime you need to use need to use NSNotificationCenter addObserver 
See [Notification center method method called multiple time ios in Tab bar (View controller)? How to remove observer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33565956/notification-center-method-method-called-multiple-time-ios-in-tab-bar-view-cont)

To implement like that, 
You need to register Observer on baseviewController viewWillAppear method and remove it on viewWillDisappear method.

On Observer method you can set values that you want to display.

Comment: This approch is consuming lot of memory..this is already in place..I am looking for an alternative..Thanks